# Copy class properties from class to a new subclass C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I've a base class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassPropertyTest
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I've some class that derive from the base class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassPropertyTest
{
    public class ClassA : BaseClass
    {
    }

}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassPropertyTest
{
    public class ClassB : BaseClass
    {
    }

}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassPropertyTest
{
    public class ClassC : BaseClass
    {
    }

}
```

I also have a masterclass that has properties to instances of each class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassPropertyTest
{
    public class MasterClass
    {
        public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
        public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
        public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now when I receive a instance of the masterclass, I need to create a new class from the property ClassA. I use reflection but I keep getting errors that the target is not valid.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ClassPropertyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Fill master class
            MasterClass o_masterclass = new MasterClass();
            o_masterclass.ClassA = new ClassA { name = "classA", value = 1 };
            o_masterclass.ClassB = new ClassB { name = "classB", value = 2 };
            o_masterclass.ClassC = new ClassC { name = "classc", value = 3 };



            //Now get class by property name
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in o_masterclass.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //Check for class A property
                if (prop.Name == "ClassA") {
                    //Create an instance of that type from ClassA
                    BaseClass instance = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType.BaseType);
                    //Copy properties from masterclass property ClassA to new instance of BaseClass
                    CopyObject<BaseClass>(prop.PropertyType.BaseType, ref instance);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copy an object to destination object, only matching fields will be copied
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="sourceObject">An object with matching fields of the destination object</param>
        /// <param name="destObject">Destination object, must already be created</param>
        public static void CopyObject<T>(Type sourceObject, ref T destObject)
        {
            //  If either the source, or destination is null, return
            if (sourceObject == null || destObject == null)
                return;

            //  Get the type of each object
            Type sourceType = sourceObject;//.GetType();
            Type targetType = destObject.GetType();

            //  Loop through the source properties
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in sourceType.GetProperties())
            {
                //  Get the matching property in the destination object
                PropertyInfo targetObj = targetType.GetProperty(p.Name);
                //  If there is none, skip
                if (targetObj == null)
                    continue;

                //  Set the value in the destination
                targetObj.SetValue(destObject, p.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

@Sergey, I've changed the CopyObject method to this:

```
  public static void CopyObject<T>(T sourceObject, ref T destObject)
        {
            //  If either the source, or destination is null, return
            if (sourceObject == null || destObject == null)
                return;

            //  Get the type of each object
            Type sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();
            Type targetType = destObject.GetType();

            //  Loop through the source properties
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in sourceType.GetProperties())
            {
                //  Get the matching property in the destination object
                PropertyInfo targetObj = targetType.GetProperty(p.Name);
                //  If there is none, skip
                if (targetObj == null)
                    continue;

                //  Set the value in the destination
                targetObj.SetValue(destObject, p.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null);
            }
        }
```

When I call it like you told me it works.

```
 CopyObject<BaseClass>(o_masterclass.ClassA, ref instance);
```

But in my situation o_masterclass.ClassA actually is prop.PropertyType.BaseType. How can I convert this type to the desired object?

Comment: In CopyObject method : `p.GetValue(sourceObject, null)` : in this case, `sourceObject` is a type, not an instance of that type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for that (or other mapping library):

```
var otherA = Mapper.Map<ClassA>(o_masterclass.ClassA);
```

By default it maps properties by name. So you even don't need to setup any configurations in this case.

In your solution you should pass sourceObject instead of it's type:

```
public static void CopyObject<T>(T sourceObject, ref T destObject)
{            
    if (sourceObject == null || destObject == null)
        return;

    //  Get the type of each object
    Type sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();
    Type targetType = destObject.GetType();

    //  Loop through the source properties
    foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProp in sourceType.GetProperties())
    {
        //  Get the matching property in the destination object
        PropertyInfo destProp = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProp.Name);
        //  If there is none, skip
        if (destProp == null)
            continue;

        //  Set the value in the destination
        object value = sourceProp.GetValue(sourceObject, null);
        destProp.SetValue(destObject, value, null);
    }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
CopyObject<BaseClass>(o_masterclass.ClassA, ref instance);
```

Also keep in mind that type can contain indexers or read-only properties.

Comment: But why it doesn't work? I made a console app to test it and in my case with different class name and properties works.

Comment: It crashes on this line  // Set the value in the destination
                targetObj.SetValue(destObject, p.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null); With the error: TargetException was unhandled

Comment: @Sergey, Automapper does indeed work, but I need to select the need property 'ClassA' by string. This also could be 'ClassB' or 'ClassC'. I wanted to be generic.

Comment: @Alex just verified - it does map all properties of your sample base class. Do you have some properties like specified in last line of my answer?